# Is it a bad idea to prevent php sessions from expiring?

Tags: php, session

I'm changing the following settings in my php.ini config file so sessions don't expire for at least a month:

```
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0 to 1
session.cookie_lifetime = 0 to 2419200
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440 to 2419200
```

I've heard though that is not a good idea to do this, is there any example on why this is not a good idea?

Comment: obvious reason: you'll end up with a buttload of stale session files sitting around, wasting space on your drive. if you haven't configured auto-subdirectory splitting of the files, you'll end up with some major overhead as the OS has to parse the session directory file EVERY time a session file is accessed.

Comment: not really because the gc is going to fire up to clean up.

Comment: no, because you're (apparently?) setting it to 0, which means the gc will never run, no matter what the gc lifetime is.

Comment: `0 => 0 to 1` means I'm changing it from 0 to 1.

Comment: then that's even worse. you're forcing the GC to run on EVERY SINGLE session-using hit on your site. that means every single session file will have to be checked for staleness on every single hit, which is a massive waste of resources. if you have 10,000 users, and they're ALL hitting the site (say) every 30 seconds, that's 600,000 session file scans per minute, for a session which will expire only once a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is that it may pose a security risk. If someone is using a public computer and doesn't explicitly logout, then anyone else can presumably access that session. Sessions also consume storage space.

Whether or not these issues should concern you depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulating session files will progressively clog your session operations much more than you could expect, especially if your system stores them in a `tmpfs` which is quite common.

It also increases security risks as guessing existing session ids gets easier as you have more session files present.